# Optimising row-wise function on data.table

Tags: r, optimization, data.table

I am having difficulty creating a fast data.table solution for a keyed join on numeric ranges. I have the following input data:

```
coverageTable <- data.table('position' = c(1:6),
                            'coverage' = c(15, 5, 20, 15, 9, 11))
variantMatrix <- data.table('start' = c(1,2,3,5),
                            'end' = c(1,2,4,6))
```

I want to return a column to variantMatrix called covered_alleles that has the value 2 if all positions within the start:end of variantMatrix are covered >= 10, taken from the coverage column in coverageTable, and the value 0 if this condition is not met.

Currently, I am using the following code, which works but is slow:

```
isCovered <- function( coverageTable, start, end ) {

   return(ifelse(all(coverageTable[.(start:end),coverage]>=10),2,0))

}

setkey(coverageTable,position)
variantMatrix[,covered_alleles:=isCovered(coverageTable,start,end),by=c('start','end')]
```

My expected output is:

```
       start   end covered_alleles
   <num> <num>           <num>
1:     1     1               2
2:     2     2               0
3:     3     4               2
4:     5     6               0
```

However, I need to run this code on millions of variants, so applying this function row-wise to variantMatrix is prohibitively slow. Is there a way to use data.table syntax to make this operation faster? Thanks!

Comment: Is `ifelse()` the bottle neck?

Answer (score 1):

For millions of variants, indexing `cumsum` will give good performance:

```
variantMatrix[,covered_alleles := 2*(c(diff(matrix(c(0, cumsum(coverageTable$coverage >= 10))[c(start, end + 1)], 2, .N, 1))) == end - start + 1)]
```

Benchmarking against a join approach:

```
variantMatrix <- data.table(start = sort(sample(2e6, 1e6)))[
  ,end := start + sample(0:10, 1e6, 1)
]

coverageTable <- data.table(position = 1:max(variantMatrix$end))[
  ,coverage := sample(20, .N, 1)
]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  join = {
    coverageTable[variantMatrix[, rn := .I], rn := i.rn, on = .(position >= start, position <= end)]
    variantMatrix <- variantMatrix[
      coverageTable[, .(covered_alleles = fifelse(all(coverage >= 10), 2L, 0L)), by = "rn"],
      on = "rn"
    ][,rn := NULL]
  },
  cumsum = variantMatrix[,covered_alleles := 2L*(c(diff(matrix(c(0, cumsum(coverageTable$coverage >= 10))[c(start, end + 1)], 2, .N, 1))) == end - start + 1)],
  check = "identical",
  times = 10,
  unit = "relative"
)
#> Unit: relative
#>    expr     min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
#>    join 67.4233 59.34943 48.3748 55.07499 38.19816 37.37327    10
#>  cumsum  1.0000  1.00000  1.0000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000    10
```

Update: in case `coverageTable$coverage` is not necessarily `1:nrow(coverageTable)`, we can get the cumulative coverage by grouping on the position:

```
variantMatrix[
  ,covered_alleles := {
    cumcoverage <- coverageTable[,.(coverage = min(coverage)), position][
      ,{
        cover <- numeric(max(position))
        cover[position] <- coverage
        cumsum(coverage >= 10)
      }
    ]
    2*(c(diff(matrix(c(0, cumcoverage)[c(start, end + 1)], 2, .N, 1))) ==
         end - start + 1)
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a range-based join into `coverageTable` to determine which of the `variantMatrix` rows each belongs to, and then summarize those based on values.

```r
variantMatrix[, rn := .I]    # "unique id" for each row
variantMatrix[2, start := 1] # to demonstrate duplicate matches
coverageTable[variantMatrix, on = .(position >= start, position <= end)
    ][, .(covered_alleles = fifelse(all(coverage >= 10), 2L, 0L)), by = .(rn)]
#       rn covered_alleles
#    <int>           <int>
# 1:     1               2
# 2:     2               0
# 3:     3               2
# 4:     4               0
```

(*Edit*: this now accounts for 0-to-many matches between them so if a `coverageTable` row matches more than one in `variantMatrix`, it should still work.)

If we want to be "slick", we can replace the `fifelse(..)` with `2L*all(coverage >= 10)` to remove one function from the stack, perhaps squeezing out a little more performance.

```r
coverageTable[variantMatrix, on = .(position >= start, position <= end)
    ][, .(covered_alleles = 2L * all(coverage >= 10)), by = .(rn)]
```

Comment: And what if rows of coverageTable can, in fact, map to more than one row in variantMatrix? (I forgot about multi-allelic sites in my example cases)

Comment: Can you provide an example of what that would look like? Does it mean the same position can appear more than once in `coverageTable`?

Comment: First it needs confirmation that that is in fact a concern of yours. From there, we'd need to know how it's supposed to look ... but I don't think it's that difficult.

Comment: see my edit undercover_camel (and @jblood94), it now handles (with little consequence) 0-to-many matches of `coverageTable` to `variantMatrix`.